# how to print columns of database using forloops in awk

Tags: for-loop, awk

hello every one i have just started learning awk and i am facing a problem
here is my data

```
    james         31 
    mary          22 
    john          28
```

i want to print some thing like this "mary age is 22 "using for loop i have written this code

```
{
  for (i=1 ;i<=FNR ;i++)
    { 
     FNR == i {print $1 " age is " $2}  
    }
}
```

buts its giving me error on the bracket

awk: awk_script.awk: line 5: syntax error at or near {
awk: awk_script.awk: line 7: syntax error at or near }

kindly tell me where i am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the for loop.  Awk does that automatically.

Given the file called names:

```
james,31 
mary,22 
john,28
```

You just need to do this on the command line:

```
awk -F ',' 'FNR == 2 {print $1 " age is " $2}' names
```

This will give

```
mary age is 22
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to do complex logic for that. see this example:

```
kent$  echo "  james         31 
dquote>     mary          22 
dquote>     john          28
dquote> "|awk 'BEGIN{OFS=" age is "}$1=$1'

james age is 31
mary age is 22
john age is 28
```